# controlPage and gestures... Changing pages not working?

Tags: ios, ios4

I created a really simple app with a controlPage with three images. Everytime I click on the dots at the base the pages changes. Everything works. The code I used is

```
@implementation myShareViewController

@synthesize  gestureStartPoint;

-(IBAction) changePage {
    switch ([pageControl currentPage]) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"changePage: In case 0");
        [view2 removeFromSuperview];
        [view3 removeFromSuperview];
        [[self view] addSubview:view1];
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"changePage: In case 1");
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
        [view3 removeFromSuperview];
        [[self view] addSubview:view2];
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"changePage: In case 2");
        [view2 removeFromSuperview];
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
        [[self view] addSubview:view3];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Then I added the following code to get the gestures (swipes)

```
#pragma mark -
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
 -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoisition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPoisition.x);
CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPoisition.y);

if (deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance) {
    NSLog(@">> Begin >> Hor. Swipe detected. We are now in the page: %i", [pageControl currentPage]);
    [self changePage];
    NSLog(@">> End   >> Hor. Swipe detected. We are now in the page: %i", [pageControl currentPage]);

}
else if (deltaY >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaX <= kMaximumVariance) {
    NSLog(@"Ver. Swipe detected");
}
}
```

Now the gestures are recoginzed alright, but the pages don't changes.

**Update with solution**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)]; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight]; 
[swipeRight release];
```

and then add a:

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{ 
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)  
    {
        // advance page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume in your touchesMoved callback you are seeing something like:

> Begin >> Hor. Swipe detected. We are now in the page: 0
>
> End   >> Hor. Swipe detected. We are now in the page: 0

This is because you aren't actually telling the [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to change pages in this code. When you are calling changePages, you are telling the view to update to reflect the current state of the PageControl.

To have this work you will need to increment or decrement the currentPage property of the PageControl based on the user swipe.

Comment: Was thinking about that. So I would have to add something like that `pageControl.currentPage = (pageControl.currentPage + 1) % 3; [self page];`. Is there a better way of doing that? For example I was checking something along the lines of UITapGestureRecognizer... Is that a good idea? Or my way is fine? Thanks again!

Comment: @fasttouch If you used the UISwipeGestureRecognizer to detect the left and right swipe direction that would probably simplify things (as @Deepak suggested).

Comment: Yep. Done that, it simplifies a lot and make the code a lot cleaner. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are expecting the swipe to just work. When you use the page control i.e. tap on it, it changes the `currentPage` property. But in this case where you are swiping on an unrelated control, you expect it to react. That doesn't happen automatically. You need to do it. You do this by detecting whether it was a right or left swipe. If it was swiped in the right direction, change the `currentPage` to the previous property. If it was swiped left, go to the next page. After doing that, call the `changePage` method.

Note, you can use the gesture recognizers provided by the framework too. They reduce the pain a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into that too. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Correct answer and I think the suggestion to use a gesture recognizer is a good one :)

Comment: OK got it. Thanks, just to help others what I did was to add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
[swipeRight release];` and then add a `- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {` at the end where I handle the direction, e.g. if `(recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)`. Working perfectly. Thanks guys.